# Can't get agora to work. The local side gives me a black screen and the remote side never connects

Tags: android, kotlin, agora.io

I run the code in Android Studio on both my phone and an emulator at the same time.
Both have the proper permissions. I checked in the System Settings.

Here is the AgoraVideoChat class I’ve made:

```kotlin
package com.example.dnaire.camera

import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.PorterDuff
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.SurfaceView
import android.view.View
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.example.dnaire.R
import com.example.dnaire.databinding.VideoCallingBinding
import com.example.dnaire.firebase.firebase
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import io.agora.rtc.IRtcEngineEventHandler
import io.agora.rtc.RtcEngine
import io.agora.rtc.video.VideoCanvas
import io.agora.rtc.video.VideoEncoderConfiguration

class VideoChatViewActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding : VideoCallingBinding
    private var mRtcEngine: RtcEngine? = null

    companion object {
        private val LOG_TAG = VideoChatViewActivity::class.java.simpleName
        private val PERMISSION_REQ_ID_RECORD_AUDIO = 22
        private val PERMISSION_REQ_ID_CAMERA = PERMISSION_REQ_ID_RECORD_AUDIO + 1
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = VideoCallingBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, PERMISSION_REQ_ID_RECORD_AUDIO) && checkSelfPermission(
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                PERMISSION_REQ_ID_CAMERA
            )) {
            initAgoraEngineAndJoinChannel()
        }

        firebase()
    }

    fun checkSelfPermission(permission: String, requestCode: Int): Boolean {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "checkSelfPermission $permission $requestCode")
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                permission
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(permission),
                requestCode
            )
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult " + grantResults[0] + " " + requestCode)

        when (requestCode) {
            PERMISSION_REQ_ID_RECORD_AUDIO -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, PERMISSION_REQ_ID_CAMERA)
                } else {
                    showLongToast("No permission for " + Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
                    finish()
                }
            }
            PERMISSION_REQ_ID_CAMERA -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    initAgoraEngineAndJoinChannel()
                } else {
                    showLongToast("No permission for " + Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    finish()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun showLongToast(msg: String) {
        this.runOnUiThread { Toast.makeText(applicationContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }
    }

    private fun initAgoraEngineAndJoinChannel() {
        initializeAgoraEngine()
        setupLocalVideo()
        joinChannel()
    }

    private val mRtcEventHandler = object : IRtcEngineEventHandler() {

        // Listen for the onFirstRemoteVideoDecoded callback.
        // This callback occurs when the first video frame of a remote user is received and decoded after the remote user successfully joins the channel.
        // You can call the setupRemoteVideo method in this callback to set up the remote video view.
        override fun onFirstRemoteVideoDecoded(uid: Int, width: Int, height: Int, elapsed: Int) {
            Log.i("testen", "VideoChatViewActivity/onFireRemoteVideoDecoded called")
            runOnUiThread { setupRemoteVideo(uid) }
        }

        // Listen for the onUserOffline callback.
        // This callback occurs when the remote user leaves the channel or drops offline.
        override fun onUserOffline(uid: Int, reason: Int) {
            runOnUiThread { onRemoteUserLeft() }
        }

    }

    // Initialize the RtcEngine object.
    private fun initializeAgoraEngine() {
        try {
            mRtcEngine = RtcEngine.create(baseContext, getString(R.string.agora_app_id), mRtcEventHandler)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e))

            throw RuntimeException("NEED TO check rtc sdk init fatal error\n" + Log.getStackTraceString(e))
        }
    }

    private fun setupLocalVideo() {
        mRtcEngine!!.enableVideo()
        val container = binding.localVideoViewContainer
        val surfaceView = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(baseContext)
        surfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true)
        container.addView(surfaceView)
        mRtcEngine!!.setupLocalVideo(VideoCanvas(surfaceView, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_FIT, 0))
    }

    private fun joinChannel() {
        Log.i("testen", "joinChannel called")
        mRtcEngine!!.joinChannel(
            "<credential>", "SeriChannel", "Extra Optional Data", 0) // if you do not specify the uid, we will generate the uid for you
    }

    private fun setupRemoteVideo(uid: Int) {
        val container = binding.remoteVideoViewContainer

        if (container.childCount >= 1) {
            return
        }

        val surfaceView = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(baseContext)
        container.addView(surfaceView)
        mRtcEngine!!.setupRemoteVideo(VideoCanvas(surfaceView, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_FIT, uid))

        surfaceView.tag = uid // for mark purpose
        val tipMsg = binding.uidText
        tipMsg.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    private fun onRemoteUserLeft() {
        val container = binding.remoteVideoViewContainer
        container.removeAllViews()

        val tipMsg = binding.uidText
        tipMsg.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    private fun onRemoteUserVideoMuted(uid: Int, muted: Boolean) {
        val container = binding.remoteVideoViewContainer

        val surfaceView = container.getChildAt(0) as SurfaceView

        val tag = surfaceView.tag
        if (tag != null && tag as Int == uid) {
            surfaceView.visibility = if (muted) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        leaveChannel()
        RtcEngine.destroy()
        mRtcEngine = null
    }
    
    // Button ClickListeners in .xml
    private fun leaveChannel() {
        mRtcEngine!!.leaveChannel()
    }

    fun onEncCallClicked(view: View) {
        finish()
    }

    fun onSwitchCameraClicked(view: View) {
        mRtcEngine!!.switchCamera()
    }

    fun onLocalAudioMuteClicked(view: View) {
        val iv = view as ImageView
        if (iv.isSelected) {
            iv.isSelected = false
            iv.clearColorFilter()
        } else {
            iv.isSelected = true
            iv.setColorFilter(resources.getColor(R.color.black), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
        }
        mRtcEngine!!.muteLocalAudioStream(iv.isSelected)
    }

    fun onLocalVideoMuteClicked(view: View) {
        val iv = view as ImageView
        if (iv.isSelected) {
            iv.isSelected = false
            iv.clearColorFilter()
        } else {
            iv.isSelected = true
            iv.setColorFilter(resources.getColor(R.color.black), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
        }

        mRtcEngine!!.muteLocalVideoStream(iv.isSelected)

        val container = binding.localVideoViewContainer
        val surfaceView = container.getChildAt(0) as SurfaceView
        surfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(!iv.isSelected)
        surfaceView.visibility = if (iv.isSelected) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
    }

}
```

And here is the corresponding (and not very pretty) layout XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_video_chat_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/remote_video_view_container"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="@color/remoteBackground">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@id/icon_padding">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/remote_back_icon_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/remote_back_icon_size"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_agora_largest" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/icon_padding"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/remote_back_icon_margin_bottom"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/uidText"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/control_panel"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.483"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/local_video_view_container" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/local_video_view_container"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@color/localBackground"
            android:onClick="onLocalContainerClick"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/control_panel"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/local_back_icon_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/local_back_icon_size"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_agora_large" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/control_panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_call"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/call_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/call_button_size"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:onClick="onEncCallClicked"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_end_call" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_switch_camera"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/other_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/other_button_size"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/control_bottom_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/btn_call"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_call"
                android:onClick="onSwitchCameraClicked"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_switch_camera" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_mute"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/other_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/other_button_size"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/control_bottom_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btn_call"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_call"
                android:onClick="onLocalAudioMuteClicked"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_unmute_normal" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_video_mute"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/other_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/other_button_size"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btn_mute"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:onClick="onLocalVideoMuteClicked"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_voice" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

It starts up, and I can connect without any error messages;
the log for the activity shows me this:

```
2021-01-12 02:21:30.175 516-516/? I/SurfaceFlinger: Display 0 HWC layers:
        type    |    handle    | flag |  format   |   source crop (l,t,r,b)    |         frame       | name 
    ------------+--------------+------+-----------+----------------------------+---------------------+------
         DEVICE | 0x75196ad080 | 0002 | RGB_565   |   0.0    0.0  600.0  600.0 |    0 1176  600 1776 | SurfaceView - com.example.dnaire/com[...]ra.VideoChatViewActivity@10775c1@0#0
         DEVICE | 0x74fbd49880 | 0000 | RGBA_8888 |   0.0    0.0 1080.0 2220.0 |    0    0 1080 2220 | com.example.dnaire/com.example.dnaire.camera.VideoChatViewActivity$_24379#0
         DEVICE | 0x75196abf00 | 0000 | RGBA_8888 |   0.0    0.0 1080.0   72.0 |    0    0 1080   72 | StatusBar$_8073#0
         DEVICE | 0x75196ad940 | 0000 | RGBA_8888 |   0.0    0.0   67.0  408.0 | 1013  328 1080  736 | com.samsung.android.app.cocktailbars[...]rservice.CocktailBarService$_13359#0
         DEVICE | 0x75196ac680 | 0000 | RGBA_8888 |   0.0    0.0 1080.0  144.0 |    0 2076 1080 2220 | NavigationBar0$_8073#0
```

But I have no idea what that’s worth.

[image: Demo screenshot]

I added a picture of how that looks in action. It is exactly the same on both devices.
And yes, I’ve generated a token under Project > Edit > Generate Temp Token, and I enabled primary and secondary certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you to check the following:

1. You are using the resource R.string.agora_app_id as your App ID. Make sure that you have added the correct App ID in the xml file.
2. In your joinChannel method, the first parameter that should be provided is your token which is supposed to be different from your App ID. For development purposes, you can do the following to [generate a temporary token](https://docs.agora.io/en/Agora%20Platform/token?platform=All%20Platforms#generate-a-token). When taking your application to production, make sure to [setup a token server](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/token_server?platform=All%20Platforms)